# not sure how to implement a drawer navigator in my project

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to implement a drawer navigator in my [project](https://github.com/practicia1234/Practicia/tree/devSam). The drawer will appear in all of the following Scenes: AllPractice, Practice, Playing Tests, Question (all tabs)

Individuals, Groups, Pending. (also tabs).

And all of the other main screens: Awards, GameOn, Uploads.

The issue is I don't know where to implement it in my project. 
All my navigation is in the navigation folder.

This is the basic code for the drawer:

```
 AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  FirstScreen: { Screen: FirstScreen },
  SecondScreen: { Screen: SecondScreen }
 });
```

Here is where all my navigation code is: its in [this](https://github.com/practicia1234/Practicia/blob/devSam/src/navigation/navigationStack.js) file
        import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

```
// Home scenes
import Home from '../scenes/Home';

// Authentication scenes
import Login from '../scenes/authentication/Login';
import SignUpStep from '../scenes/authentication/SignUpStep';
import SelectTeachers from '../scenes/authentication/SelectTeachers';

// import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard'
// import FeedScreen from '../components/FeedScreen'
import AwardsScreen from '../scenes/award/AwardsScreen';
// import StudentsScreen from '../components/StudentsScreen'
import GameOnScreen from '../scenes/game/GameOnScreen';

// All practice scenes
import AllPractice from '../scenes/practice/AllPractice';
import Practice from '../scenes/practice/Practice';
import PlayingTests from '../scenes/practice/PlayingTests';
import Questions from '../scenes/practice/Questions';
import Individuals from '../scenes/practice/Individuals';
import FirstScreen from '../scenes/drawer/firstScreen';
import SecondScreen from '../scenes/drawer/secondScreen';

// Group
import Groups from '../scenes/group/Groups';

// Upload
import UploadsScreen from '../scenes/upload/UploadsScreen';
import Pending from '../scenes/upload/Pending';

// Constant for tab menus
const submissionMenu = {
  screen: TabNavigator({
    All: { screen: AllPractice },
    Practice: { screen: Practice },
    PlayingTests: { screen: PlayingTests },
    Questions: { screen: Questions }
  }, {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    flex: 2 / 3,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#33ACDE',
      labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 12,
            },
      tabStyle: {
        width: 50
                },
    }
  }
  )
};
const studentMenu = {
  screen: TabNavigator({
    Individuals: { screen: Individuals },
    Groups: { screen: Groups },
    Pending: { screen: Pending }
  }, {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    flex: 1 / 2,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#33ACDE',
    }
  }
  )
};

// Navigation defined
const navigator = StackNavigator({
  home: { screen: Home },
  signup: { screen: SignUpStep },
  login: { screen: Login },
  selectTeachers: { screen: SelectTeachers },
  dashboard: {

    screen: TabNavigator({
      Submissions: submissionMenu,
      Students: studentMenu,
      Awards: { screen: AwardsScreen },
      GameOn: { screen: GameOnScreen },
      Uploads: { screen: UploadsScreen }
    }, {
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#33ACDE',

      }
    }),

    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'PRACTICIA',
      headerLeft: null,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#33ACDE',
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: 'white'
        }
      }
    }
});

export default navigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawer Navigation is like a Tab navigation. It means if you want to use a Drawer to offer a user to navigate your app, then forget about the tabs.

Or, if you want to use a drawer just as a controller like you put some buttons on it.

then, it will be like this.

```
AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  FirstScreen: { Screen: navigator },
 });
```

I put your 'navigator' on the drawer navigation. Then you can use AppDrawerNavigator as a root.

Then, you can use 'contentComponent' in drawerNavigatorOption to put some buttons or view.

Comment: Sorry I am a little new to this. Where would i put this code in my navigation stack file?

Comment: i think i did what you said and put this at the bottom. I get the following error mesage: Route FirstScreen should declare a screen in the red screen.

Comment: Then, did you export AppDrawerNavigator and put on index.js? @SamRao